# How to call C# dll method in electron App?

Tags: node.js, angular, dll, electron, electron-packager

I have an electron app which reads credit card details from card reader.
They provided a c# dll to interact with app. I have no idea about how to read the dll methods from electron app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check the exposed functions in the dll using [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/). Then use the node module [ffi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ffi) to call the exposed functions in that dll.

Comment: do ffi need python ?

Comment: Can you please expand on your answer to included explanations from the links? Links can easily die.