# How to call a C# DLL method from electron?

Tags: c#, dll, electron

I have an electron app which needs to call some methods from an existing DLL. The DLL is a C# DLL and I tried using electron-edge-js but got some errors like : The edge module has not been pre-compiled for Electron version

Can you please let me know how can I call C# DLL methods from electron? Also if you can point me to a sample code for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to call C# dll method in electron App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50753458/how-to-call-c-sharp-dll-method-in-electron-app)

Comment: Being new to this, I had read somewhere that ffi supports code written in C and C++ only. Does that support calling C# DLL as well?

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with the issue that well. From the link above it seems possible, but you'll have to try yourself.